# How to create initially hidden field in the form layout?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to create field in form layout that's initially hidden (completely, including field label)?

I don't want to call `cmp.getEl().up('.x-form-item').setDisplayed`[1] for these fields after rendering because it causes flicker and other “effects”.

[1] as I know that's the only way to hide form field including label.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup the form field's xtype to hidden. So, you'll have something like this:

```
{
id:'my_field_id',
name: 'my_field_name',
xtype: 'hidden'
}
```

You can add the field like this:

```
Ext.getCmp("myFormPanel").add({
    id:'my_field_id',
    name: 'my_field_name',
    xtype: 'textfield'
    });
Ext.getCmp("myFormPanel").doLayout();
```

And remove it like this:

```
Ext.getCmp("myFormPanel").remove(Ext.getCmp("my_field_id"));
Ext.getCmp("myFormPanel").doLayout();
```

I hope this is what you want.

Comment: But I don't want hidden field, I want — for example — hide/show some fields and avoid form flicker when form is rendered.

Comment: Are you sure you want hide/show and not enable/disable field ?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, create a CSS class in your document with either (depending on your needs) 'display:none' OR 'visibility:hidden'. Call this class, say, 'invisible-class'.

Create another class with either 'display:block', 'display:inline' OR 'visibility:visible' and call this class say, 'visible-class'.

For the form field you wish to be invisible when its rendered you would set its 'cls' property to 'invisible-class', i.e.:

```
cls:'invisible-class'
```

And when you want the field to be visible, use the method:

```
addCls('visible-class')
```

ALTERNATIVELY- when you want to make the item visible use the method:

```
removeCls('invisible-class')
```

i.e. mycomponent.removeClass('invisible-class')

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler method if you just need to hide this single field and its field label would be to create a separate label object for it.  It might be easier to just hide the label instead of deal with the CSS to hide the fieldLabel.

You might be able to add a listener to the render event of the layout managing panel to do something like this...

> var cmp = Ext.getCmp(fieldID);

```
if((cmp.hidden) && cmp.previousSibling() != null) 
   && (cmp.previousSibling().xtype =='label'){
   cmp.previousSibling().hide(); 
}
```